# 'Sport' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to coding in general and have an assignment where I need to create a newsletter site using Visual studio using ASP.net & C# (Sorry if I get some of the jargon wrong, I am new to this)

I'm having the above error and can't quite figure out the problem.

Below is the code for the edit news page. I have 2 db's inner joined as you can see from the select command. I want to have a dropdown list so the author can select a sport as currently in the database it's listed as numbers which isn't useful if they do not know what the numbers represent. I was able to get a dropdown list working, however when I added "SelectedValue" so that when the author selects a sport it will update the db, though, this is when I got the error. I has the same string of code in an insert page and it works so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="editnews.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_editnews" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
            <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="newseditrows" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:newsconnection %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT News.headline, News.Image, News.paragraph, Sports.sport, News.Sport, News.date, News.lead, News.authorID, Sports.id
                            FROM News 
                            INNER JOIN Sports ON News.Sport = Sports.id
                            ORDER BY date DESC"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [News] SET [headline]=@headline, [Image]=@Image, [paragraph]=@paragraph, [Sport]=@sport, [date]=@date, [lead]=@lead, [authorid]=@authorid WHERE [id]=@id">

            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="headline" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Image" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="paragraph" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Sport" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="date" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="lead" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="authorid" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sportlist" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:newsconnection %>' 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id], [sport] FROM [Sports]">

        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:ListView ID="displayedit" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="newseditrows"
            DataKeyNames="id">

            <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageLabel" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <span style=""><%--id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel1" /><br />--%>
                    Headline:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineTextBox" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageTextBox" /><br />
                    Paragraph:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphTextBox" 
                                 TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50" Rows="8"/><br />
                    <br />Sport:
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="SportTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sport") %>' />--%>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Sport" runat="server" 
                                        DataSourceID="sportlist" 
                                        DataTextField="sport" 
                                        DataValueField="id"
                                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Sport") %>' >

                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <br />
                    <%--date:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateTextBox" /><br />--%>
                    Lead:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadTextBox" /><br />
                    <%--authorID:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDTextBox" /><br />--%>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" ID="UpdateButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <span>No data was returned.</span>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <span style="">headline:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineTextBox" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageTextBox" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphTextBox" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportTextBox" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateTextBox" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadTextBox" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDTextBox" /><br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" /><asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="CancelButton" /><br />
                    <br />
                </span>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageLabel" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholderContainer" style=""><span runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" /></div>
                <div style="">
                    <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="DataPager1">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                            <asp:NumericPagerField></asp:NumericPagerField>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True" ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False"></asp:NextPreviousPagerField>
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>

                </div>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <SelectedItemTemplate>
                <span style="">id:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" ID="idLabel" /><br />
                    headline:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("headline") %>' runat="server" ID="headlineLabel" /><br />
                    Image:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageLabel" /><br />
                    paragraph:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("paragraph") %>' runat="server" ID="paragraphLabel" /><br />
                    Sport:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("sport") %>' runat="server" ID="SportLabel" /><br />
                    date:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("date") %>' runat="server" ID="dateLabel" /><br />
                    lead:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("lead") %>' runat="server" ID="leadLabel" /><br />
                    authorID:
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("authorID") %>' runat="server" ID="authorIDLabel" /><br />
                    <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                    <br />
                <br />
                </span>
            </SelectedItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing dropdownlist SelectedValue with `Eval` statement?

Comment: Yes @HassanNisar , However I still received the error.

Comment: Can you add error description? What it say?

Comment: OK sorry it is mentioned in title. I am not sure about case-sensitivity of Bind function but have you tried writing `Bind("sport")` instead of `Bind("Sport")`?

Comment: Also tried that and still receiving the error. I am stumped :/

Comment: OK I found the reason :) ... check the answer

Answer (score 0):

**ListControl.SelectedValue:** 
Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects the item in the list control that contains the specified value. (Inherited from ListControl.)
[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Here you are trying to select a value which doesn't exists in the value fields.

`SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id") %>'` should work.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Sport" runat="server" 
                                    DataSourceID="sportlist" 
                                    DataTextField="sport" 
                                    DataValueField="id"
                                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("id") %>' >
```

Comment: What you actually mean to say is don't do this in designer. This is a strong case to handle the OnDataBinding event.

Comment: No. You don't necessarily have to take manipulate data in the cs file or handle `OnDataBinding` event. Markup of dropdownlist compelete enough to select a value from existing data source. All you have to focus that you select a value which exists in value field.

Comment: I tried that, It allowed me to edit the contents of the dropdown box, however when I clicked update I got a new error.

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Sport', table 'C:\USERS\AARON\DOCUMENTS\PROJECT02\APP_DATA\NEWS.MDF.dbo.News'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Then when I click allow nulls in the database itself, I get no error, however, the database won't update.

Comment: You cant set it this way. You will need to either parse it in the sql statement or handle it in the code behind.

Comment: @user3113377 this is another issue you identified. Are you able to solve it?